# Different style of progress bar in Mahapps

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I don't know why Mahapps progress bar still has the same style despite the fact that I change style in App.xaml (other controls works fine).
Is there any other way than creating from zero a style for this control?

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Orange.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800"
    Background="WhiteSmoke">


<StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Controls:Tile Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="200"/>
    <Controls:Tile Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="200"/>
    <Controls:Tile Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="200"/>


</Grid>

    <Controls:MetroProgressBar Value="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: This is fixed after v1.5.0, currently available with the pre-release, which is also availabe via NuGet. The final v1.6.0 is coming soon™